# How to perform a Tap using Appium 2.0 C#

Tags: appium, w3c, browserstack

I miss touchactions but they are deprecated so I want to understand how to write them with W3C standards. I want to move to a location and then tap that location.  Here is what I am trying but its not performing:

```
 Actions actions = new Actions(_IOSdriver);
 actions.MoveToLocation(263, 495).Click();
 Thread.Sleep(2000);
 actions.Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the mobile: tap command?

Link for reference:
https://appium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/

Comment: C# Tap is not provided. Two Finger tap does not show how to perform with Location(x,y) coordinates.